# Source file ...g.cs could not be found (from a downloaded project)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I downloaded [this project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-Build-Manage-and-fdd0074a) to play around with and get an understanding about wpf pages, however no matter what i do, i cant get it to build.

> Source file 'C:\Users\mikeh\Desktop\How to Build, Manage and Navigate the User Interface of a WPF Application\C#\ApplicationNavigation\obj\x86\Debug\View\Page3.g.cs' could not be found.

I get this error for each xaml file in the project. I doublecheck app.xaml is set to `ApplicationDefiniton`, everything else is set to `page`.

I deleted the bin folder (although this folder did not exist in the downloaded zip)

How can i get this application to build? There has to be a way to force build this file without doing a build.

Comment: That usually happens when you inadvertently open up a `.g` file. Try closing all documents, clean, and rebuild. Could also be misnomer if you have `Build + Intellisense` selected instead of `Build` on the Error List window while you have a `.g` file open. The build succeeds, but you are shown a ton of errors.

Comment: I've tried that. can you see if you can open and build without issues?

Comment: It builds just fine for me using VS2017

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you downloaded the project and saved it to `Desktop` or `My Downloads` and instantly tried to open it, the problem may be due to a long filepath.

Rename the `How to Build, Manage and Navigate the User Interface of a WPF Application` folder to just `Demo` and try again. That should work.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-Build-Manage-and-fdd0074a/view/Discussions#content